# "Too many open files" after migrating from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

After migrating from Tomact 7 to Tomcat 9.0.20 (running with same Java Version 1.8.0_25) we have a problem with our JSF2 web application on Linux RHEL 7. After some time we get Exceptions like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbs/webapps/ACM/WEB-INF/acm-config.xml (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
```

After searching around a while, I have found out that there are many open file descriptors to xhtml files, by executing this command (where 4025 is the Tomcat process ID):

```
ls -l /proc/4025/fd


lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 238 -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 239 -> pipe:[3661823]
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 24 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/websocket-api.jar
l-wx------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 240 -> pipe:[3661823]
lrwx------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 241 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 243 -> pipe:[3661824]
l-wx------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 244 -> pipe:[3661824]
lrwx------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 245 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 246 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/msgBox.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 247 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/msgBox.xhtml
lrwx------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 248 -> socket:[3667364]
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 249 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/searchpage.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 25 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/jasper.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 250 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/searchpage.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 251 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/portal/nav/portalheader.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 252 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/portal/customizing/nav/menu.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 253 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 254 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/nav/bottomPanel.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 255 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/nav/bottomPanel.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 256 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/msgBox.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:01 257 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 258 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 259 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 26 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/ecj-4.9.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 260 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 261 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 262 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/common/barcodefunction_incl.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 263 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/portal/nav/portalfooterAll.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 264 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartner.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 266 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartner.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 267 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/portal/nav/portalheader.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 268 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/portal/customizing/nav/menu.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 27 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/catalina-ha.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 274 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartner_topnav.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 275 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/msgBox.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 276 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/msgBox.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 277 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 278 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 279 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 28 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/jsp-api.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 280 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 281 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 282 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 283 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 286 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 287 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 288 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 289 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 29 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/annotations-api.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 290 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 291 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 292 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 293 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartnerparent_incl.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 294 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 295 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 296 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 297 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 298 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartnerHierarchySimilarAddresses.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 299 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartnerchild_incl.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 3 -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 30 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 300 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 301 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 302 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 303 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 304 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/form/partner/crmpartnerHierarchySimilarAddresses.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 305 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 306 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 307 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 308 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 309 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 31 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 310 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 311 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 312 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 313 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 314 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 315 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 316 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 317 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 318 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 319 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 08:58 32 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/lib/catalina-ant.jar
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 320 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 321 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 322 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 323 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 324 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 325 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 326 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 327 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 328 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
lr-x------. 1 f4mHttp f4mHttp 64 May 16 09:02 329 -> /f4m/tomcat/tomcat_f4mbscrm/webapps/ACM/resources/components/calendar.xhtml
```

This is not the complete list - there are many more.

The number of listed files goes up and down.
For me it seems that and xhtml (or one of its used components) has an open file descriptor as long as a page is shown in Browser.

If I deploy the same application on Tomcat 7 again, I can only see open file descriptors for JAR Files, Sockets, but not NEVER for xhtml's.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Compare /etc/init.d/tomcat (I assume this is same on RHEL) and $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/* to see if anything changed.  Often you have to add ulimit directives to the /etc/init.d/tomcat which may have been in 7 but not in 9?  Maybe something changed in one of the conf files?

Comment: The problem is not, that the limit has changed. The problem is that Tomact 7 NEVER created an open file descriptor for the xhtml files - button Tomcat 9 does...

Comment: Do you get any startup warning about cache not being big enough?  I remember having to add a directive to increase the cache size upgrading to 8 from 7 (and same for 9).  conf/context.xml (Context | Resources element), I set cachingAllowed="true" and cacheMaxSize="100000" attributes and was able to run the app, but this is only in the case where tomcat is serving static content, ideally there should be a web server in front doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file leak has occured in JSF2 MyFaces implementation, see also here: https://marc.info/?l=myfaces-dev&m=152536956716792&w=2

I was able to find the problem by using this tool: http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/